# Houseplant Troubleshooting: Why is this Plant Shedding Leaves?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, succulents

I've been caring for this plant (unsure of the name) for about two months--and over this period, it's remained perfectly healthy. In the last week, however, it's begun to lose its leaves, and I'm not sure what the cause is or how to resolve it. Here's a photo:

[image]

I water it only after the soil is completely dry. Though it's been losing leaves, it's also been growing new branches from the base of the plant. 
I've tried to move it closer to the sunlight, but it doesn't appear to be making a difference.

Any advice you have would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leaves look to be fleshy, so I believe this is Crassula ovata, common name Jade or Money plant. You say you water when the soil is completely dry; if you mean you wait for all of the soil in the pot to be completely dried out, that's too long for the plant. Whilst these plants should not be overwatered, going into drought in between waterings will mean leaf loss.

If the soil is currently completely dry, give it a good water now - leave it sitting in water in the bottom tray for 30 minutes, then empty that out. Water again when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry the soil in the pot is shrunken from the sides. Water well, and empty out the tray after 30 minutes, and again 30 minutes after that if it refills, so that the plant is not left sitting in water. Continue in this way ongoing.

These plants do very well in bright daylight or sun, so you don't need to find a sunny spot for it. If regrowth of leaves does not occur along the bare branches, you will need to cut back each one to where healthy growth does occur so that you can create a bushy plant. Further care info https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/jade-plant.html

Comment: If this is, in fact, a C. ovata it is totally starved of light and badly etiolated. The node length on the upper growth appears to be 2-3 inches, which is well outside the norm. According to the link above, they recommend a few hours of sunlight in order to thrive. Close to sunlight isn't cutting it. It needs direct sunlight, IMO, assuming it's a C. ovata.

Comment: @TimNevins - whatever the link says, I've always grown  mine on a north facing windowsill I(ie bright daylight) where it never gets any sun at all, but its perfectly healthy and not etiolated. If this plant is grown in full sun, though, it develops paler leaves with red rims.

Comment: I'll defer to your practical experience. It looks etiolated to me. That is not the normal growth habit for C. ovata in my limited experience.

Comment: I'm not saying it is or isn't etiolated - I think its very hard to tell when the plant has lost almost all its leaves....

Comment: Thank you to both of you--this is extremely helpful.